# Infinite load_files on Google Colap

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I use python3 on Google Colab and the method load_files from sklearn.datasets is running infinitely.

*On Google Colab Notebook*

```
!pwd
/content

!ls 
cat_dog ...

load_files("/content/cat_dog/Colab Notebooks/dataset/training_set")
infinite load
```

I have my dataset on the virtual machine with a 9000 images.
If I execute load_files ("path") on my real machine it takes few seconds.

Comment: I wrote Hello everybody at the beginning but it's not appear :/

Comment: Please edit your post to state a question.

Answer (score 0):

The only place you can write your local files in Colab is on /tmp . It is advisable to prepare all the data formatting prior you take the data to Colab and work with all the data in memory.

Various ways you can deal with file system.

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb

```
# Download the file.
!gsutil cp gs://{bucket_name}/to_upload.txt /tmp/gsutil_download.txt

# Print the result to make sure the transfer worked.
!cat /tmp/gsutil_download.txt
```

Hope it helps.